# sqlalchemy empty schema and no tables

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use sqlalchemy via a Database first approach and generate the models for the existing database structure. The db is a standard SQLServer(express).

I can connect to my database and query it via the following

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

__connectionString = "DSN=databaseDSN;Trusted_Connection=yes"

db_engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % __connectionString, echo=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=db_engine))

result = db_session.execute("SELECT * FROM debug.BasicTable")
for row in result.fetchmany(10):
    print(row)
```

When I try to reflect the database structure below I am unable to see any of the actual tables and the following raises a NoSuchTableError

```
myTable= Table('debug.BasicTable', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=db_engine)
```

from a common tutorial http://pythoncentral.io/sqlalchemy-faqs/

I should be able to reflect the table objects

```
Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.reflect(db_engine)

meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=db_engine)
```

However there are no table objects in meta.tables at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `debug.BasicTable` is most likley not the name of your table. The name of your table is `BasicTable` and `debug` is its schema. So:

```
Table('BasicTable', meta, schema="debug", autoload=True, autoload_with=db_engine)
```